# Rails effective way of looping through daterange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, each

I have ScheduleDay model as;

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ScheduleDay id: 1, from: "2017-01-21 00:00:00", to: "2017-01-30 00:00:00", weekday: 100, weekend: 200, weekly: 90, available: true, check_in: "09:00", check_out: "18:00", min_stay: 2, sevendays: false, check_in_day: nil, created_at: "2017-01-14 11:25:18", updated_at: "2017-01-14 11:27:00">, #<ScheduleDay id: 2, from: "2017-02-05 00:00:00", to: "2017-02-15 00:00:00", weekday: 150, weekend: 200, weekly: 140, available: nil, check_in: "09:00", check_out: "18:00", min_stay: 3, sevendays: false, check_in_day: nil,  created_at: "2017-01-14 15:53:21", updated_at: "2017-01-14 15:54:43">, #<ScheduleDay id: 3, from: "2017-03-15 00:00:00", to: "2017-06-15 00:00:00", weekday: nil, weekend: nil, weekly: nil, available: false, check_in: nil, check_out: nil, min_stay: 1, sevendays: false, check_in_day: nil, created_at: "2017-01-14 15:56:01", updated_at: "2017-01-14 15:56:57">, #<ScheduleDay id: 4, from: "2017-08-05 00:00:00", to: "2017-09-30 00:00:00", weekday: 500, weekend: 500, weekly: 500, available: true, check_in: "09:00", check_out: "18:00", min_stay: 7, sevendays: true, check_in_day: "Saturday", boat_id: nil, created_at: "2017-01-14 16:01:00", updated_at: "2017-01-14 16:02:10">]>
```

I have another date range and I would like to loop over my date range in ScheduleDay table and if record is found get some data. If not found then get data as well. I tried couple different way but I m looking for the most efficient way in ruby.

```
    first = Date.parse("05.2.2017")
    last = (Date.parse("16.2.2017"))

    schedules = ScheduleDay.where(from: Date.today..(last+1.day))

    dates = []


    (first..last).each do |date|
        flag = 0    
        catch :date_found do
            schedules.each do |s|   
                (s.from.to_date..s.to.to_date).each do |d|
                    puts date
                    puts d

                    if date == d
                        flag += 1
                        puts 'found'
                        throw :date_found
                    end

                end

            end
            if flag == 0
                puts 'date not found'
            end 
        end

    end
```

This is what I have tried so far. But the problem here is I can not access the record if it is not found. If I take;

```
if flag == 0
   puts 'date not found'
end
```

inside `schedules.each...` loop then it prints not found for every record in ScheduleDay. I want to loop through all ScheduleDay record and if not found get some data.

**EDIT:**

I have database records saved by the user. User can customize any date of the year by selecting date range and pricing. I ask user base pricing as well.

So, lets say user entered 15.01.2017 & 21.01.2017 custom price: 100 and base price 200 (base price will be used if date is not found on database date-range).

I would like to return json array of February. So I need;

```
01.01.2017 -> custom price exists? if not get base price
02.01.2017 -> custom price exists? if not get base price
...
15.01.2017 -> yes! custom price exists get custom price
16.01.2017 -> yes! custom price exists get custom price
17.01.2017 -> yes! custom price exists get custom price
18.01.2017 -> yes! custom price exists get custom price
...
21.01.2017 -> yes! custom price exists get custom price
...
31.01.2017 -> custom price exists? if not get base price
```

then create json

**EDIT2**

What if I use;

```
first = Date.parse("05.2.2017")
last =  Date.parse("16.2.2017")

(first..last).each do |date|
            schedules.each do |s|   
                d2 = (s.from.to_date..s.to.to_date)
                puts d2 === date
                puts d2
                puts date                       
            end
        end
```

`===` checks date is in the range.

Comment: Seeing `catch` and `throw` is a sign this code is going to be a beast to verify with tests. What are you doing here? Why can't you just `return` the value or skip to the next element with `next`?

Comment: I am trying to get if first & last date range record is found on database. If found I will get ScheduleDay data if not get other data from another table. I used `catch` and `throw` because I need to go outer loop

Comment: Using `catch` for control flow is very bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for warning, but do you have any suggestions? I would appreciate.

Comment: It's not clear to me actually what you're trying to do really. Could you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: Thank you edited the question

Comment: Most of the time you can tackle this problem without resorting to `catch` and `throw`. The built-in [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method could probably do the job a lot more efficiently than what you have here.

Comment: Do you really have to do this enormous loop there, there must be a way to do this with a fairly simple SQL query.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are trying to load ScheduleDay records with from..to containing any date from first..last. If so than most effective way would be to use SQL. For instance in postgresql you may achieve this by very simple query:
`ScheduleDay.where("(from, to) OVERLAPS (?, ?)", first, last)`